# Django's find the path to setting.py

Tags: python, django

Until not long ago, I used to do this in many places in my Django app:

```
from  MyApp import settings
```

This required that I put settings inside my MyApp directory. I realized that is wrong, so I started using:

```
from django.conf import settings
```

But now I can't figure out how to find the path to `settings.py` from withing my code. Earlier I could use `settings.__file__`.

As a workaround I defined inside `settings.py`:

```
PATHTOSELF = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

Any ideas how to find the path to `settings.py`?

Comment: I've got to ask, why do you need the path to it? Are you looking for a path to the _project root_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
import os
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Place it on top inside of your settings.py. You can then import PROJECT_ROOT at any point in your code like this:

```
from myapp.settings import PROJECT_ROOT
```

Comment: Did you mean that I do the same thing as PATHTOSELF?

Comment: I've updated the answer to make it more clear. We use this virtually everywhere. Just use the direct settings import from your app. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: What's the difference between this and PATHTOSELF? (beside that `abspath` call) I was thinking maybe the is a django way ...

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I must have over-seen the "PATHTOSELF" in your original question :P

Comment: well, PATHTOSELF was a last moment hack. The PROJECT_ROOT is a more descriptive and clearer variable name

Comment: So you had it all right from the start :-) I don't know of any other solution (although there may be one), but we use this a lot in huge projects and never had an issue.

Comment: @Well I will accept your answer, because it's also good to have reassurance the we do things right.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
import os
PROJECT_PATH = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```